# Copy file to another file with support in symbolic links in c

Tags: c, file, copy, symlink

I have a task that I should make a program that's copy file to another file with support in symbolic links. I already write a program that copies the file to another file but without a symbolic link. In the task, I have to use the functions: readlink(2), stat(2), getopt(3)
I have read what each function do but I didn't get how I can support symbolic link with scanf and all the program.

I really appreciate any help in this case.

EDIT: the note in the task: "support copying of symbolic links in copy. Use -l to copy link contents. Without -l copy the file linked by the symbolic link. Use readlink(2), stat(2), getopt(3)"

Comment: The OS normally handles symbolic links automatically, you don't need to do anything special in your program. Do you mean that if the original file is a symlink, you should make another symlink instead of copying the contents?

Comment: I edit the post, and post the task that asked me to support the copying of symbolic links may it will be more clear.

Comment: So what part of it are you having trouble with? Use `lstat()` (not `stat()`) to determine if the source is a symlink. If it is, call `readlink()` to get its target, and then use `symlink()` to create the new symlink at the destination.

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)